# How to give INSTALLDIR folder permission in WIX?

Tags: permissions, installation, wix

I am designing a WIX 3.6 installer project, during the installation we need to grand the user create file permission to the install folder(INSTALLDIR, especially with the default install folder, the Program Files, the user normally can't create file in the installation. We've experienced some failures). I guess it can be achieved by setting a Permission element, with CreateFile property. However, the INSTALLDIR is a directory, and only such elements as CreateFolder, File, FileShare, Registry, ServiceInstall can have permission element. So could anyone tell me how to do that? My directory declaration is something like this:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
      <Directory Id='MANUFACTUREFOLDER' Name='$(var.ManufacturerName)'>
        <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="$(var.ProductName)">
```

Thanks!

UPDATED:
Now I have managed to create a file (not the deployed file. But a generated file based on one deployed file, and it is generated in a custom action in commit phase). However, I now have a problem deleting the deployed file I just described (because there is no use of it after the other file is successfully generated). When the installation folder is Program Files, I can't delete it in the custom action. It says access denied.

Another thing is, I really don't understand the purpose of CreateFolder element. If its aim is to create a folder, as its name implies, don't nested Directory(s) do the same thing, as in my example code? And I think it is more clear to describe the folder structure there since it is very common to separate the Component elements (in which CreateFolder elements will reside) and the Directory elements. The Component will just use DirectoryReference to refer to the correct directory. Secondly, it is also common that multiple Components reside in the same Directory. So if I add a CreateFolder to one of those Components, with the default directory as the common parent directory of those Components, what does it even mean? It is really not intuitive of such a structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted, CreateFolder elements may have Permission elements, and they default to the directory of the parent component if no directory is specified. So the structure would look something like the following.

```
<Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="$(var.ProductName)">
  <Component>
    <CreateFolder>
      <Permission>
      </Permission>
    </CreateFolder>
  </Component>
</Directory>
```

However, based on Vista and Windows 7 restrictions and Windows Logo guidelines, I wouldn't be surprised if you still have issues with this, since the Program Files directory is pretty locked down. After install you should not be writing to this directory.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Please see my update on the original post because the comment has a character number limit. I have some more question about the CreateFolder element.

Comment: Do you have an update to add to this question, or are you talking about a different question you posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346936/unable-to-delete-deployed-file-during-installation-with-wix-installer

Comment: I am indeed talking about the question you mentioned. But I also added some update in this post to describe what problem I am having. Because they are quite relevant. If you have any opinion, please comment on either post. Basically I really don't understand the CreateFolder element. What's the purpose of it, e.g, in your example code?

Comment: There are two cases where I use CreateFolder. One is to set permissions on directories, similar to the example above. The other is for when I need my installer to create an empty directory.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared my questions (somehow). It makes sense that we use it when we want to set permission. But in order to create an empty directory, like I mentioned, doesn't a nested Directory structure do it (and I think it is clearer there). I think it is really confusing especially the CreateFolder element can appear under any Component, which might share the same parent Directory. For example, what if the two Permission elements under two Component but for the same directory have contradicting permission? Plus, the name CreateFolder is also confusing. But that's how they made it :)

Comment: I think that even if you use Directory elements to create a directory structure, if you never actually install a component into that directory then it will not be created on the client machine.