# Run an executable during install and delete it after

Tags: c#, .net, wix

I have a WIX project and would like to execute a .exe when all the files are copied. But I don't want this .exe to be "installed". How can I do that? The reason is, that my installer drops file in a virtual folder in IIS and letting the .exe there after the install is not an option.

Comment: How about a Wix custom action? (C# code that runs as part of the installer)

Comment: yes, but I can't find the proper parameters in the custom action to run a file that isn't a component installed (FileKey).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted to have the file sitting in a folder inaccessible via IIS, so that every installer that needs to run the .exe during the installation process points there. Ex:

```
<Property Id="EXEAPPLOCATION">
      <DirectorySearch Id="mpfAppFolder" Depth="1" Path="C:\Program Files\mypath\Tools\">
        <FileSearch Id="my.exe" Name="my.exe"  />
      </DirectorySearch>
    </Property>


    <CustomAction Id="RunExecutable" 
                  Property="EXEAPPLOCATION" 
                  ExeCommand='-source="c:\test.txt"'
                  Execute="deferred" 
                  Return="check" 
                  Impersonate="no"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have used SfxCa.exe to pack the exe in a custom action wrapper dll. This would have caused the exe to be extracted to a temporary directory during install and deleted after. A custom action could then be used to execute the file during install. That would have been a much cleaner approach to running a temporary exe.